# Find specific JS for the mouseover effect on website

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good afternoon, currently im trying to reverse a website to find the mouseover event  on the menu links because the client wanted to remove on mouseover and just keep on click which i already did, but the thing is that the programmer who performed this website before me did not specify were it is  and it is not along with the script for " on click event" which makes me wonder where it is , im starting to question if its in the html css but cant find it either, could someone check and see if they find where is the event for mouseover listed?

http://spgeotecnia.w30.mycloud.pt/

Comment: you should be able to use the Developer Tools in the browser to trace it. Find the element and look what events are attached to it, find the mouseover event and see where it leads.

Comment: Did already it is not specified,  seems like it may be executing in css??

Comment: in that case examine the CSS properties of the element to see what rules apply to the element

Comment: Im not being able to find atleast clearly ive checked the params but it keeps on hover showing the sub menus

Comment: In CSS you're probably looking for a "hover" effect